# icarousel not shown

Tags: ios, sdk, icarousel

I added iCarousel to my App, but it doens't work. In my other App it works.
I linked the view, the delegate and the datasource in InterfaceBuilder

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TermineView.h" 
#import "iCarousel.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate>{

IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView;
NSURLRequest *Request;

...
}
...

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet iCarousel *carousel;


@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize carousel;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
carousel.type = iCarouselTypeRotary;
carousel.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 250.0);
[self.view addSubview:carousel];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 - (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
 self.carousel = nil;

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark iCarousel methods

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
//generate 100 buttons
//normally we'd use a backing array
//as shown in the basic iOS example
//but for this example we haven't bothered
return 100;
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
if (button == nil)
{
    //no button available to recycle, so create new one
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

//set button label
[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

return button;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Button tap event

- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
//get item index for button
NSInteger index = [carousel indexOfItemViewOrSubview:sender];

[[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button Tapped"
                             message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You tapped button number %i", index]
                            delegate:nil
                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                   otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
}




 @end
```

any ideas what I have done wrong?
I see an empty view....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting break points inside your datasource methods to see if they're being called?

How about using the debugger to check that the dataSource property of the carousel has been correctly set on your iCarousel view?

My guess is that the dataSource has not been correctly bound, but it's hard to be sure without more information.

Answer (score 0):

please, check first `NSArray` array not be nil for that following method write it and after put breakpoint on datasource and delegate method after compile and build ....it's working code ...

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    //set up data
    //your carousel should always be driven by an array of
    //data of some kind - don't store data in your item views
    //or the recycling mechanism will destroy your data once
    //your item views move off-screen
    self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        [self.items addObject:@(i)];
    }
}
```

Try it .... 
thanks